# create records only when boxes checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following PATCH action is getting the following parameters

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", [...], "contractgroup"=>
{"articolocontractgroups_attributes"=>
{"0"=>{"articolo_id"=>"0", "id"=>"425"}, 
 "1"=>{"articolo_id"=>"true", "id"=>"426"}, 
 "2"=>{"articolo_id"=>"true", "id"=>"427"}, 
 "3"=>{"articolo_id"=>"0", "id"=>"428"}}, "contractgroup_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Add"}
```

however the controller action is invoking the parameters in a mistaken manner, as no records are being created:

```
params[:contractgroup][:articolocontractgroups_attributes].each do |id, attrs|
  if params[:articolo_id] == "true"
    @articolocontractgroup = Articolocontractgroup.new
     (articolo_id: params[:contractgroup][:articolo_id], 
      contractgroup_id: params[:contractgroup][:contractgroup_id])
    @articolocontractgroup.save
  end
end
```

where is this messed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check `attrs[:articolo_id] == "true"` instead `params[:articolo_id]`